# 'get' in a code tag does not render properly as a keyword

Tags: bug, syntax-highlighting

I found `get` in [my code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38190354/5482465) does not properly render as a C# keyword. Is this a bug?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That is a bug in the Prettify highlighter, and unfortunately bugs should be reported on their [GitHub project](https://github.com/google/code-prettify), as explained in [What is Syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work/184109#184109). I went ahead and made one of the committers aware of this [issue](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/commit/7c601842dae2195f0995379111fe262a71a7ca86#commitcomment-18120034).

Here is my analysis:

As shown the `get` keyword is marked as `pln` where `kwd` is expected. `set` has the same issue but that goes a bit unnoticed because it is recognized as an `typ`.

[image: prettify classes]

On closer inspection of the Prettify Issues it looks like the keywords got updated [here](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/pull/384). I'm not sure why but  AFAICT the [commit that follows](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/commit/7c601842dae2195f0995379111fe262a71a7ca86) undoes those changes again, leading to the effect that `get` no longer is recognized as a keyword in the `lang-cs`.

It can take a while before the Prettify main branch is released and after that an SE dev has to pull and release on the sites here. That will take 6 to 8 weeks ... on both ends ...

#### 6 to 8 ...

... later there is progress on the Google Prettify front: [Fixes are pushed to master](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/pull/467)

Comment: Yes. I would advice OP to investigate the code, find the socalled "bug" (==lack of a certain feature OP desire) implement it / correct code and make a pullrequest on github.

Comment: Fair enough @davidkonrad reworded a bit.

Comment: Q: If it takes 6-8 weeks for prettify and then 6-8 weeks for the SO team, when should we expect the changes? ... A: still 6-8 weeks.

Comment: Now it's just waiting 6 to 8 more for SE to pull the changes... what should be done when you sum several 6 to 8's? n*(6 to 8) or (6 to 8)^n? Darn, I should have read @KyleMit comment...